# redirect loop nginx & uwsgi & django

Tags: python, django, nginx, uwsgi

I've inherited a Python / Django project. I'm setting up a dev server for new changes which is a direct clone of the live server. I'm trying to configure nginx config so that it will stop redirecting.

At the moment it gets stuck in a https redirect loop. If i look at network tab within dev tools for chrome i can see a 302 GET loop going on and on.

**here is the nginx conf file:**

```
server {
    listen          443 ssl;
    server_name     dev.mywebsite.com;
    ## DYNAMIC CONTENT
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  unix:///tmp/website.sock;
        include     uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_param HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO  $scheme;
    }
    ## STATIC CONTENT
    location ^~ /static/ {
        alias       /home/website/src/www/static/;
        access_log  off;
        expires     30d;
        gzip        on;
        gzip_http_version   1.1;
        gzip_vary       on;
        gzip_comp_level     6;
        gzip_proxied        any;
        gzip_types      text/css text/javascript application/javascript application/x-javascript;
        gzip_buffers        16 8k;
        gzip_disable        "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";
    }
        ssl_certificate         /home/website/ssl/mywebsite/crt;
        ssl_certificate_key     /home/website/ssl/mywebsite/key;
    ## FAV ICON
    location = /favicon.ico {
        alias       /home/website/www/static/img/_app/favcion.ico;
    }
}
server {
   listen       80;
   server_name      *.mywebsite.com;
   rewrite      .*  https://$host$request_uri permanent;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mywebsite.com;
    rewrite .* https://www.mywebsite.com$request_uri permanent;
}
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name mywebsite.com;
        ssl_certificate         /home/website/ssl/mywebsite/crt;
        ssl_certificate_key     /home/website/ssl/mywebsite/key;
    rewrite .* https://www.mywebsite.com/ permanent;
}
```

**uwsgi:**

```
[uwsgi]
processes           = 1
threads             = 1

module              = mywebsite.wsgi:application
chdir               = /home/website/src/
home                = /home/website/venv

stats               = /tmp/website.stats
socket              = /tmp/website.sock
pidfile             = /tmp/website.pid

max-requests        = 1000
listen              = 128
chmod-socket        = 777
harakiri            = 60
cpu-affinity        = 1

vacuum              = true
master              = true
no-orphans          = true
thunder-lock        = true
disable-logging     = true
```

I've obviously replaced all URL's with mywebsite. Also the dev subdomain exists and is correctly pointing to the server

If anyone can give assistance it would be greatly appreciated. I've spent far too many hours on this task

Comment: Do you see any requests hitting your django app before you get a redirect back?

Comment: Whats the best way to monitor the requests? I'm watching the nginx log with tail, and can't see any messages in there. One problem is that I don't know how to monitor django hits. I've tried enabling all debug / logging features via settings.py

Comment: it depends on your setup, the easiest way is to setup logging for `django.request`, in this example there is everything you need https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/logging/#examples

Comment: Thanks a lot irqed i'll look into this, I have far more experience with ruby/rails, php/laravel/phalcon/zend, getting my head around python/django and its logging is doing my head in somewhat!